# Why do researchers only count the number of multiplications when analyse the time complexity of Matrix Multiplication?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, matrix-multiplication

In this [article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-inch-closer-to-matrix-multiplication-goal-20210323/) about the recent breakthough in Matrix Multiplication, it quotes Chris Umans's words:

> Multiplications are everything. The exponent on the eventual running time is fully dependent only on the number of multiplications. The additions sort of disappear.

I was wondering how I should understand this. Why the number of additions doesn't matter?

Comment: now I realised that the distance of my example is NOT metric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the article was written by someone who does not understand matrix multiplication.

> the number of additions is equal to the number of entries in the matrix, so four for the two-by-two matrices and 16 for the four-by-four matrices.

With the classic matrix multiplication algorithm (which is the one explained in the example) between two $4\times 4$ matrices, each coefficient of the product requires $3$ additions, so a total of $3\times 16 = 48$ additions, not $16$.

Usually, when it is said that only multiplications matter and not additions, it means of **matrices**, not **coefficients**.

For example, a "naive" divide-and-conquer strategy compute $A\times B$ where $A,B$ are matrices of size $n\times n$ by doing $8$ products of matrices of size $\frac{n}{2}\times\frac{n}{2}$ (and some additions of matrices, but those are done in complexity $O(n^2)$, which is negligible in front of the complexity of matrix multiplication). That way, the complexity verifies $C(n) = 8C\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + O(n^2)$ and it is easily proven that $C(n) = O(n^3)$, so this strategy is not an improvement.

The [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm#Algorithm) use a divide-and-conquer strategy to improve complexity: it does $7$ products of matrices of size $\frac{n}{2}\times\frac{n}{2}$ and some additions, so the complexity verifies $C(n) = 7C\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) + O(n^2)$ and we get $C(n)\simeq O(n^{2.8})$.

In the two examples above, the number of matrices multiplications matter much more than the number of matrices additions. But in both, the number of multiplications/additions on coefficients is not compared.

It is confirmed in the article:

> Volker Strassen reportedly set out to prove that there was no way to multiply two-by-two matrices using fewer than eight multiplications. Apparently he couldn’t find the proof, and after a while he realized why: There’s actually a way to do it with seven!

Comment: I understood what you said about multiplication/additions of matrices. But what do you mean by multiplications/additions on coefficients?

Comment: $5 \times 7$ is a multiplication of coefficients. $\begin{pmatrix}5 & 2 \\3 & 7\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}1 & 8 \\2 & 4\end{pmatrix}$ is a multiplication of matrices.

Comment: Sorry it's may be dumb question: what do you mean by "But in both, the number of multiplications/additions on coefficients is not compared"? I didn't see any multiplications/additions on coefficients in both algorithms.

Comment: In both algorithms, additions on coefficients are done when adding matrices (so $n^2$ additions for the sum of two $n\times n$ matrices). Multiplications on coefficients are done in the base case, that is the multiplication of two matrices of size $1 \times 1$ (which is the same as the multiplication of two coefficients). The complexity $C(n)$ counts the total number of arithmetic operations on coefficients, may they be multiplications or additions.

Comment: I see, so the time complexity of Matrix Multiplication indeed measures the number of additions and multiplications on coefficients. This article is kinda misleading.